# library to abstract text parsing in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, token

I'm about to parse a lot of files, with a precise hierarchy for the XML ones and a precise syntax for the others. I would like to abstract these files at *"token level"* to simplify my code and logic. I also need UTF-8 support.

Is there a library, or perhaps a library only formed by several headers, that can do this in C++?

EDIT:

supposing that my file is something like that

```
COLOR=red Language=en
COLOR=blue Language=se
COLOR=green Language=fr
```

with token level i mean that i can access this values after parsing in this way:

```
Object.getValue(color, 1)
```

and this should return `red`.

Comment: What do you mean by *token level*?

Comment: @DougRamsey i have added more informations in the first post.

Comment: This looks very custom. Unless these files are in some known standard format that often get parsed for applications, I can't imagine there is an existing library that already does this. I think you are going to have to write the parsing code yourself.

Comment: @DougRamsey what can be a more standard approach?

Comment: Create a class to represent the data in each line. Instantiate those classes during the parsing of the file, and keep the object in some collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is [boost::spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html), that I think may be what you are looking for. You can use it to create rules for parsing input. I personally have never used it but heard good comments for it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Boost.Spirit is hands down the best parser generator framework there is. No contest.